On the classification of finite schemes over the reals
As part of Humanity's Last Exam I wanted to enter a question about (counting) the equivalence classes of finite schemes over the reals of length 4 resp. 5. Two referees suggested that this can be found on Math Stack Exchange resp. algebraic geometry textbooks. However, I searched and could not find the sources hinted at.
Denote the base field by $k$. Note, that the scheme classification can also be phrased in terms of classifying (commutative) finite length $k$-algebras $A$. The length will be denoted by $n=\text{rk}_k(A)$.
For algebraically closed fields Bjorn Poonen showed in 2006 that (independent of $\text{char}(k)$) there are finitely many equivalence classes if and only if $n\leq 6$. In that paper he also gave the classification for $n\leq 6$ - the actual classification being dependent on the characteristic. Onda also gave a classification in the case $n=7$ and $\text{char}(k)\in\{2,3\}$, which was the last missing part for a complete classification in case $n=7$. But the field $k=\mathbb{R}$ is not algebraically closed, although Poonen discusses in Remark 2.2 a construction of infinitely many equivalence classes for $n>6$, $|k|=\infty$ and $\text{char}(k)\neq 2$ which obviously includes $k=\mathbb{R}$.
There is a paper in Spanish that might be relevant, but unfortunately I do not speak Spanish.
Here is what I know about the classification for $k=\mathbb{R}$, $m$ counts the number of isomorphism classes followed by a list of representatives for each isomorphism class (correct me, if I am wrong):

$n=0$: $m=1$, $0$ (corresponds to $\emptyset$ the empty scheme)
$n=1$: $m=1$, $\mathbb{R}$
$n=2$: $m=3$, 

$\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$,
$\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2)$,
$\mathbb{C}$


$n=3$: $m=5$, 

$\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$,
$\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2)$,
$\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{C}$,
$\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^3)$,
$\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2)$


$n=4$: $m=13$, 

$\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$,
$\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2)$,
$\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{C}$,
$\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2)\times\mathbb{R}[y]/(y^2)$,
$\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^3)$,
$\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2)$,
$\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2)\times\mathbb{C}$,
$\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}$,
$\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^4)$,
$\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^3,xy,y^2)$,
$\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2,y^2)$,
$\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]/(x^2,xy,xz,y^2,yz,z^2)$,
$\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2)$,


$n=5$: $m=26$, 

$\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$,
$\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2)$,
$\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{C}$,
$\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2)\times\mathbb{R}[y]/(y^2)$,
$\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^3)$,
$\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2)$,
$\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2)\times\mathbb{C}$,
$\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}$,
$\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^4)$,
$\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^3,xy,y^2)$,
$\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2,y^2)$,
$\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]/(x^2,xy,xz,y^2,yz,z^2)$,
$\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2)\times\mathbb{R}[y]/(y^3)$,
$\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2)\times\mathbb{R}[y,z]/(y^2,yz,z^2)$,
$\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^3)\times\mathbb{C}$,
$\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2)\times\mathbb{C}$,
$\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2)$,
$\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^5)$,
$\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^4,xy,y^2)$,
$\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^3+y^2,xy)$,
$\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^3,xy,y^3)$,
$\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^3,x^2y,y^2)$,
$\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]/(x^3,xy,xz,y^2,yz,z^2)$,
$\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]/(x^2,xz,y^2,yz,z^2)$,
$\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2,xy,x^2+z^2,xz,yz)$,
$\mathbb{R}[x,y,z,w]/(x^2,xy,xz,xw,y^2,yz,yw,z^2,zw,w^2)$,



I have found related questions on the internet, but without answers (here and also here).
Question: Where does one find these results? What sources are there in general for classifying finite length schemes over fields?

You never really say so bit apparently you are only interested in affine schemes.

@MartinBrandenburg Since I am only interested in finite schemes (not just finite type!), they are always affine. Correct me, if my understanding is wrong.

Yes, sorry. I totally forgot that finite morphisms are defined to be affine. Ignore what I said :D
